# Task Scheduling and Powershell's Start-Job

Tags: powershell, cron, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, start-job

Currently, I try to run a PowerShell-Script, which starts a few instances with `Start-Job -name $jobname -Scriptblock { ... Code ...};`

This PowerShell-Script should be executed every 15 minutes in the WIndows Task Schedule. I run this process with highest priviledges, and the Power-Shell-Script starts perfectly - the problem is:
The Code, which is executed by Start-Job doesn't work.

I think the problem is that the "Start-Job" can not work with the task schedule together.

Do you know how to solve that? Are there any settings to configure?

Comment: Does `Start-Job |Wait-Job` make a difference?

Comment: Start-Job should work fine with the scheduler, you should supply your job code

Answer (score 2):

If no any control at the end of script, Powershell will immediately exit once background job is created. So try to add below control code:

```
$runningJobs = Get-Job -State Running 
    while($runningJobs.Count -gt 0){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $runningJobs = Get-Job -State Running
}

Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
```